# perl module for creating CLI

Tags: perl, command-line-interface, cpan, mod-perl

I wish to know is there any existing perl module which can provide the framework
to create new CLI commands ?

Thanks
Arpit

Answer (score 2):

There are lots and lots of them. For example [see here](http://www.slideshare.net/nickpatch/modern-getopt-for-command-line-processing-at-yapcna-2011).

To get you started, perhaps have a look at [Getopt::Long::Descriptive](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt%3a%3aLong%3a%3aDescriptive). Another suggesion, if you want to create command-driven applications (like `git` commands) is to have a look at [App::Cmd](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3aCmd).

If you're using Moose, there are modules which integrate it with the above (e.g. MooseX::Getopt and MooseX::App::Cmd) though I find the start up time quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [MooseX::App](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aApp) with success in my last project. It's a Moose based solution, and it's easy to use.

If you don´t want Moose, [App::Cmd](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3a%3aCmd) is good.